# Why curl return nothing in this case?

Tags: php, curl

I need to retrieve some JSON data from the following endpoint:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

This is the code I tried:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$postResult = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
   print curl_error($ch); 
} 
curl_close($ch);
```

However, I don't get any results. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` make your requests insecure. Why do you have these enabled?

Comment: Are you sure it should be a POST request? A GET request already returns some data

Answer (score 3):

You are making a POST request, but after making some tests with that endpoint I concluded the request should be a GET.

Also, you shouldn't disable SSL verification or your requests will be potentially insecure

This should work:

```php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$getResult = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
   print curl_error($ch); 
} 
curl_close($ch); 

print_r($getResult);
```

Also, you should decode your json string:

```php
$data = json_decode($getResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this codes, May it will help you.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$postResult = curl_exec($ch); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postResult);
echo "</pre>";
if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
 // print_r($postResult);
} 
curl_close($ch); 

?>
```

Let me know if you have any Query